# Non-deprecated way to call NavigationLink on Buttons

Tags: swiftui

This is the old way of calling `NavigationLink` on `Button`s

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: String? = nil
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: View1(), tag: "tag1", selection: $selection) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: NotView1(), tag: "tag2", selection: $selection) {
                    EmptyView()
                }

                Button("Do work then go to View1") {
                    // do some work that takes about 1 second
                    mySleepFunctionToSleepOneSecond()
                    selection = "tag1"
                }

                Button("Instantly go to NotView1") {
                    selection = "tag2"
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation")

        }
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly. It can go to different `View` targets depending on which button is clicked. Not only that, it guarantees all work is done **BEFORE** navigating to the target view. However, the only issue is that `'init(destination:tag:selection:label:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: use NavigationLink(value:label:) inside a List within a NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView`

I get `NavigationStack` is awesome and such. But how can I translate the code to use the new `NavigationStack` + `NavigationLink`. Especially, how can I make sure work is done **Before** navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using new `NavigationStack` and its path property you can do much more. Your example will be transformed to

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = [String]()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {
                Button("Do work then go to View1") {
                    // do some work that takes about 1 second
                    mySleepFunctionToSleepOneSecond()
                    path.append("tag1")
                }

                Button("Instantly go to NotView1") {
                    path.append("tag2")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation")
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { route in
                switch route {
                case "tag1":
                    EmptyView()
                case "tag2":
                    EmptyView()
                default:
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check this [video](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/250/whats-new-in-swiftui-for-ios-16). There you can find more use cases.

Comment: This doesn't produce the same result

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: The screens get stacked so they replace the original view on both macOS and iOS, instead of providing a side panel for navigation on macOS like NavigationView does. NavigationSplitView is closer but also appears and behaves differently from NavigationView on macOS

Comment: @EvgenyK how can I access `path` inside a nested view?

Comment: @koen You can pass it in nested views explicitly `MyView(path: path)`, also you can use create your own EnvironmentValue and setup `path` in there

Answer (score 2):

For using non deprecated and after doing some work if we want to go to next view or in anyview there is something called ".navigationDestination". Let's see that using simple example.

```
    @State var bool : Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
           VStack {
              Text("Hello, world!")
            
              Button {
              //Code here before changing the bool value
                  bool = true
              } label: {
                  Text("Navigate Button")
              }
          }.navigationDestination(isPresented: $bool) {
              SwiftUIView()
          }
       }
   }
```

In this code we change take bool value as false and change it to true when our work is done using button.

```
.navigationDestination(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, destination: () -> View)
```

In .navigationDestination pass the Binding bool and provide the view you want to navigate.

You can use .navigationDestination multiple times.

Hope you found this useful.